# calling a method on a type(not instance)

Tags: rust

In this code:

```
for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
   numbers.push(u64::from_str(&arg)
   .expect("error parsing argument"));
}
```

I understand u64 is a type, from_str is from trait FromStr. So it means u64 implements FromStr.

But here I am able to call from_str without creating instance of u64.

How does it work?

Comment: In other languages this is called a "static" method. from_str didn't take a "self" parameter, which makes it "static" and you can call it directly on the type.

Comment: Read about [Associated Functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions) in The Rust Programming Language book.